# Getting Location With getLastKnownLocation() does not get the right location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

i'm developing Android application that's deal with Google Maps Api ,  i tried to get my current location with using `mMap.getLastKnownLocation();` then get `latitude` and `longitude` after that' a pass to a method that's move the camera to my location

**This is the part of getting my location**

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager
            .getBestProvider(criteria, false));

    if( location != null ){
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        AddMarkerAndMoveCamera(latitude,longitude);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
```

**this is the part of moving the camera**

```
 public void  AddMarkerAndMoveCamera(double lat,double lng)
{
    LatLng MyLocation = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MyLocation).title("This is Your Location ! Now !"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MyLocation,15));


}
```

**this is what i get in application runtime .**[image: my marker position and my real position]

if there is any idea about how can i get the real location  not just `lastknownlocation` **'d be appreciated.**

Comment: Where is the GetLocation() method ?

Comment: @Blackkara Sorry i  correct it  with ` getLastKnownLocation() ; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Getting Location With getLastKnownLocation() does not get the right location

Because it's getting last known location of the passed provider in this method.

You need fresh location. To make this, [check this link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

**EDIT**

After you implement required things in the above link, You can do something like this.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    AddMarkerAndMoveCamera(latitude,longitude);
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
 }
```

Comment: Thank for you interest in helping me to solve my problem , but it little bit confused between my code  , and yours ! .. can you add or remove from my code to fit !

Comment: Yes right. Because you need fresh location. So, to achieve this you must make location request.

Comment: Cant i use Location to get fresh location without the mess in the the link above ?

Comment: Sorry, the content in the link was from official android resource.
It was the fused location provider. Anyway, you can also use LocationManager to get fresh location, check here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html